# Python ConfigParser KeyError:

Tags: python-2.7, configparser, keyerror

I am following an example to read a config file from the following: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples

But I get a `KeyError` and can't figure out why. It is reading the files and I can even print the sections. I think I am doing something really stupid. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import ConfigParser
import logging

config_default=ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

class Setting(object):
    
    def get_setting(self, section, my_setting):
        
        default_setting = self.default_section_map(section)[my_setting]

        return default_setting

    def default_section_map(self,section):
        dict_default = {}
                
        config_default.read('setting.cfg')
        sec=config_default.sections()

        options_default = config_default.options(section)
        
        logging.info('options_default: {0}'.format(options_default))
        
        for option in options_default:
            try:
                dict_default[option] = config_default.get(section, option)

                if dict_default[option] == -1:
                    print("skip: %s" % option)
            except:
                print("exception on %s!" % option)
                dict_default[option] = None

            return dict_default

        return complete_path

if __name__ == '__main__':

    conf=Setting()
    
    host=conf.get_setting('mainstuff','name')
    #host=conf.setting

    print 'host setting is :' + host
```

My config file is named `setting.cfg` and looks like this:

```
[mainstuff]
name              = test1
domain              = test2

[othersection]
database_ismaster   = no
database_master     = test3
database_default    = test4

[mysql]
port                = 311111
user                = someuser
passwd              = somecrazylongpassword

[api]
port                = 1111
```

And the Error is this...

> exception on domain! Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "./t.py", line 51, in 
> host=conf.get_setting('mainstuff','name')   File "./t.py", line 14, in get_setting
> default_setting = self.default_section_map(section)[my_setting] KeyError: 'name'

Comment: In my case the config file was being read using a relative path and my development environment was executing the script form a different directory so it wasn't finding the config file at all. When I ran it myself it worked fine, but I didn't realise what my IDE was doing at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have no `general` section. in order to get the hostname you need something like

```
[general]
hostname =  'hostname.net'
```

in your `setting.cfg`. now your config file matches the program -- maybe you prefer to adapt your porgram to match the config file? ...this should get you started at least.

**UPDATE:**

as my answer is useless now, here is something you could try to build on (assuming it works for you...)

```
import ConfigParser

class Setting(object):

    def __init__(self, cfg_path):
        self.cfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        self.cfg.read(cfg_path)

    def get_setting(self, section, my_setting):
        try:        
            ret = self.cfg.get(section, my_setting)
        except ConfigParser.NoOptionError:
            ret = None
        return ret


if __name__ == '__main__':

    conf=Setting('setting.cfg')
    host = conf.get_setting('mainstuff', 'name')
    print 'host setting is :', host
```

Comment: Hi @hiro protagonist Thanks for your answer. The thing is I forgot to change that when I posted this code. I changed the config file so as not to reveal too much.  So I have now updated the code above like this  'host=conf.get_setting('mainstuff','name') 'and just to confirm its still giving the same error. Sorry about that.

Comment: hmmm... works for me. (by the way: `complete_path` is not defined in your original code.)

Comment: could you try to `print self.default_section_map(section)`? this should help to debug...

Comment: Oh I thought that was it for a minute 'complete_path' which should not be there. I took it out and I get the same error. If it works for you I'm wondering what the heck is it?

Comment: If I try that I get the following

Comment: exception on domain!
{'domain': None}
exception on domain!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 53, in <module>
    host=conf.get_setting('mainstuff','name')
  File "./t.py", line 15, in get_setting
    default_setting = self.default_section_map(section)[my_setting]
KeyError: 'name'

Comment: Yes Thank you very much. That is definitely something I can work with.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that your complete file path is `setting.cfg`. If you put your file in another folder or if it is named different, Python is going to report the same `KeyError`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs mainly due to 2 reasons:

1. Issue in reading the config file due to not getting the proper path. Absolute path may be used. Try reading the config file first whether any issue.

   `f = open("config.ini", "r")`

   `print(f.read())`
2. Not been able to find mentioned **section** in config file.

Comment: In this case i used `config.read(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+"/../conf/general.conf")` to refer the complete path and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was that the config file name is case sensitive. **setting.CFG** instead of setting.cfg